# The xsl-fo convert pdf, How to Restart page numbering from 1 in each chapter in PDF

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

### The xsl-fo convert pdf, How to Restart page numbering from 1 in each chapter in PDF

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a page-sequence for each chapter. You can set the initial page number of each sequence:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="chapter" initial-page-number="1">
```